Why does pandas Grouper groups edge not align with expectations?
Given a simple series with a DateTime index, I want to group the Series into 4 month bins:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample Series with a datetime index
index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='B')
random_numbers = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=len(index))
s = pd.Series(random_numbers, index=index)

# Group by 4-month frequency and find index of maximum value
result = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4M')).idxmax()

print("Grouped Indexes:")
print(result)

However, when I print the groups, I get:
Grouped Indexes:
2015-01-31   2015-01-07
2015-05-31   2015-02-11
2015-09-30   2015-06-04
2016-01-31   2015-10-13
Freq: 4M, dtype: datetime64[ns]

I was expecting:
2015-01-01
2015-05-01
2015-09-01
i.e. three groups (12 months / 4 months = 3 groups) starting at those dates.
How should I interpret the output and am I using Grouper wrong?

You are using 'M' (now deprecated; in the future it will be 'ME'), which breaks at the end of the month. Hence, you're getting four groups:
result.index

DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-31', '2015-05-31', '2015-09-30', '2016-01-31'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='4ME')

# group 1 ends with '2015-01-31', group 2 with '2015-05-31', etc.

You are looking for 'MS', which breaks at the start of the month:
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4MS')).idxmax()

2015-01-01   2015-01-07
2015-05-01   2015-05-05
2015-09-01   2015-09-14
Freq: 4MS, dtype: datetime64[ns]

To get start and end per group:
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='4MS')).apply(lambda x: x.index[-1])

2015-01-01   2015-04-30
2015-05-01   2015-08-31
2015-09-01   2015-12-31
Freq: 4MS, dtype: datetime64[ns]


To get the expected start dates for your groups, use pd.date_range() with freq='4MS' to create a date range that starts at the beginning of each 4-month period. Then, use pd.cut() to divide the index into these custom bins, ensuring correct group alignment. This approach will yield groups starting on the desired dates like 2015-01-01, 2015-05-01, and 2015-09-01.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

(...)
# Manually set the period start dates
bins = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', periods=4, freq='4MS') 
# '4MS' starts on the 1st of Jan, May, Sep, Jan
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)

# Group by custom periods
result = s.groupby(pd.cut(s.index, bins)).idxmax()

print("Grouped Indexes:")
print(result)

